# How to get Emails from Salesforce Support when due to some reason Email-to-case is not working

Tags: email2case, monitoring

How to get Detailed Email from Salesforce Support that Email-To-Case is failing and unable to create Cases either too many large address in To address field etc.
I know About Apex email so don't suggest that.
Thanks in Advance for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Is it Normal Email to Case or On Demand Email To Case?

Comment: "Normal" as in agent-based E2C, a feature no longer supported

Comment: On Demand Email To case

Answer (score 0):

If Any User is configured as Admin user that is used to create Case(you can check it from Support Settings -lightning --Automated Case User) ,they receive the Email if Some Emails failed to create Case or encountered any Error.it does not need any Extra Setup(Realised it after so many research)